# cakephp messaging system scheme/model/controller Best Practice?

Tags: mysql, cakephp, model, controller, has-and-belongs-to-many

I am trying to implement a simple messaging system for my users.

I am not an habtm expert, so any assistance will be appreciated!

Here is what I got this far, please make any suggestions!! (cake1.3)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `app_messages` (
  `id` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `from_user_id` int(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `title` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `body` text,
  `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `app_messages_users` (
  `id` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `message_id` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `to_user_id` int(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `read` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `replied` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `trash` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

Message.php
var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'User' =>
            array(
                'className'              => 'User',
                'joinTable'              => 'messages_users',
                'foreignKey'             => 'message_id',
                'associationForeignKey'  => 'to_user_id',
                'unique'                 => true
            )
    );


User.php
var $hasMany = array(        
        'Message' => array(            
            'className' => 'message',            
            'foreignKey' => 'from_user_id',
            'dependent'     => true       
        )
```

So now, my question is, Am I doing this correct?

How do I go around creating a SEND MESSAGE function, to insert correct values to both tables?
I am a total noob regarding HABTM relationships, but I am trying to learn. Have spent several hours reading about it on the web, but still, need to ask if I am going the right way.

Thanks for your time!!
-Tom

Comment: you can take a look at my "conversations" sql table @ https://groups.google.com/d/msg/cake-php/BlOQsyuFnEc/2YXduSde0mwJ . this reduces redundancy by grouping them together via conversation. uses 3 tables then.

Comment: Had a look, and, actually, I have already looked at that discussion when fiddling around for some instructions/best approaches ;) How do you go about in the models/controllers to save the messages when sending and so on?

Answer (score 0):

Given that your join table has additional fields (`read`, `replied`, `trash`), you should not use an HABTM relationship. If you do, you won't be able to access them from your application. So instead, you should configure two hasMany associations through a new model for the join table. It is well explained [here in the CookBook](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany-through-the-join-model).

So you'll end up having something like this:

```
// User.php
class User extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'MessageUser' /* you can call this 'SentMessage' or something that makes more sense */
    );
}

// Message.php

class Message extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'MessageUser'
    );
}

// MessageUser.php

class MessageUser extends AppModel {
    public $belongsTo = array(
        'User', 'Message'
    );
}
```